# How to get HTTP headers in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working with an app that will download remote files from the web to the local Documents folder of the app.

The user needs to know the `Content-Length` (i.e: file size) before deciding to download or not, to avoid wasting resources.

I have seen the answer in this question [How to download file in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219848/how-to-download-file-in-swift)

but that answer downloads the whole file.

and using:

```
String(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://example.com/file.txt")!)
```

will download the file, not the headers.
I am looking for an alternative to

`curl --headers "http://example.com/file.txt"`

but for swift... Is there a way to let iOS operating system do that for me? like `shell` or `shell_execute()` or something like that?

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565149/get-http-header-fields-only-on-iphone

Comment: Example for content type, easily adaptable to content length: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35768662/2227743